# Java - Dynamic GridLayout

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a dynamic GridLayout using the following code:

```
package resizablegui;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

class GUIHandler extends JFrame {
    JSpinner widthSpinner;
    JSpinner heightSpinner;
    JPanel board;

    private JPanel resizer() {
        final JPanel resizer = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        final JPanel resizer_wrapper = new JPanel();

        JLabel widthLabel;
        JLabel heightLabel;

        SpinnerModel widthModel;
        SpinnerModel heightModel;
        resizer_wrapper.setLayout(new BoxLayout(resizer_wrapper, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        widthModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(8, 4, 32, 1);
        heightModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(8, 4, 32, 1);

        ResizeWindow onResize = new ResizeWindow();

        widthLabel = new JLabel("Width: ");
        resizer.add(widthLabel);

        widthSpinner = new JSpinner(widthModel);
        resizer.add(widthSpinner);
        widthSpinner.addChangeListener(onResize);

        heightLabel = new JLabel("Height: ");
        resizer.add(heightLabel);

        heightSpinner = new JSpinner(heightModel);
        resizer.add(heightSpinner);
        heightSpinner.addChangeListener(onResize);

        resizer.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        resizer_wrapper.add(resizer);

        return resizer_wrapper;
    }

    private JPanel board(int width, int height) {
        final JPanel board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(width, height));
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
                JButton button = new JButton(x+", "+y);
                board.add(button);
            }
        }
        return board;
    }

    public GUIHandler() {
        super("Board");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        board = board(8,8);

        add(resizer(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private class ResizeWindow implements ChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            int width = (Integer)widthSpinner.getValue() * 45;
            int height = (Integer)heightSpinner.getValue() * 45;

            setSize(width,height);
        }
    }
}

public class ResizableGUI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUIHandler gui = new GUIHandler();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(350,350);
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The goal, as you can probably tell, is to have an 8x8 grid of buttons, that can be made larger (ex 9x10, 10x10...) or smaller (ex 6x8, 4x4) based on the values of the spinners. The code compiles well, but upon trying to resize the dialog, the program freezes and crashes.

Comment: How exactly does it crash? If you get an exception stacktrace, please post it here. If it goes into an infinite loop, please run it under a debugger and pause the execution to see exactly where it hangs.

Comment: @yole It just runs without responding to any further input. There is no error message, and the program never actually closes or says "not responding."

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why your code freezes and crashes, it didn't do that for me.

Anyway, I still see problems with your code.

Since you want a dynamic grid you need the ability to remove/add buttons to the grid as the spinner is used. So, I would create and empty "board" panel and add it to the GUI. Then I would rename your "boar(...)" method to "resetBoard(...)" as this method should be used to just remove/add buttons, not create a new panel.

The next problem is your looping code in this new "resetBoard(...)" method. The outer loop should be for the height and the inner loop for the width, since you will be adding rows of buttons to the grid, one at a time.

So the restructuring of this method might look like:

```
private void resetBoard(int width, int height) {
        board.removeAll();
    board.setLayout( new GridLayout(0, width) );
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            JButton button = new JButton(x+", "+y);
            board.add(button);
        }
    }
}
```

So now you need to create the board and add buttons to it:

```
//board = board(8,8);
board = new JPanel();
resetBoard(8, 8);
```

Finally, in the ChangeListener you need to reset the button on the board, not change the size of the frame:

```
int width = (Integer)widthSpinner.getValue();
int height = (Integer)heightSpinner.getValue();
resetBoard(width,height);
board.revalidate();
//pack(); pack the frame is you wish
```

Also, when you first create the frame, don't set the size manually let the pack() method do the work for you:

```
//gui.setSize(350,350);
gui.pack();
```